# Force close when setting onclick

Tags: java, android

I created a button and assigned it 1 by doing

```
remove.setId(0 + count);
```

Then I tried to put that button in my onCreate bundle to use it

```
Button remove = (Button)findViewById(1);

remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

When I create the button remove in my oncreate it runs but as soon as I add my onclick listener I dont get any errors but when I run it it force closes

Log

```
12-12 13:42:06.172: D/AndroidRuntime(19502): Shutting down VM
12-12 13:42:06.172: W/dalvikvm(19502): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416bbd40)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502): Process: com.th3ramr0d.armytrooptotask, PID: 19502
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.th3ramr0d.armytrooptotask/com.th3ramr0d.armytrooptotask.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5102)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at com.th3ramr0d.armytrooptotask.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:45)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2173)
12-12 13:42:06.178: E/AndroidRuntime(19502):    ... 11 more
```

Here is my full file

```
package com.th3ramr0d.armytrooptotask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public int count = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button addTroopBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addTroop);

    addTroopBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(count <= 5)
            {
            inputName(v);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
    });

    Button remove = (Button)findViewById(1);

    remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
}

public void inputName(final View v){
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    //alert.setTitle("Enter Name and Rank");
    alert.setMessage("Please Enter A Name");

    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
    final EditText input = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(input);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      Editable name = input.getText();
      addTroop(name);
      }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        // Canceled.
      }
    });

    alert.show();
}

public void addTroop(Editable name){

    LinearLayout mainPage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.manageTroopsMain);

    if (count <= 5)
    {
    //CREATE NEW LINEAR LAYOUT
    LinearLayout addTroopLayout = new LinearLayout(this);   

    //CREATE LAYOUT PARAMS FOR LAYOUT
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    newLayout.bottomMargin = 10;

    //STYLE NEW LINEAR LAYOUT
    addTroopLayout.setTag("addTroopLayout" + count);
    addTroopLayout.setLayoutParams(newLayout);
    addTroopLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);     

    //CREATE NEW BUTTONS
    Button newTroop = new Button(this);
    Button remove = new Button(this);
    Button change = new Button(this);

    //CREATE LAYOUT PARAMS FOR BUTTONS
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams newTroopParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 20f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rmvBtnParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .5f);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams chngNameParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, .5f);


    //STYLE NEW BUTTONS
    newTroop.setText(name);
    newTroop.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    newTroop.setLayoutParams(newTroopParam);
    remove.setId(0 + count);
    remove.setText("-");
    remove.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    remove.setLayoutParams(rmvBtnParam);
    change.setText("...");
    change.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL|Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    change.setLayoutParams(chngNameParam);

    //ADD VIEWS TO NEW LAYOUT
    addTroopLayout.addView(newTroop);
    addTroopLayout.addView(remove);
    addTroopLayout.addView(change);

    //ADD NEW LAYOUT TO mainPage LAYOUT
    mainPage.addView(addTroopLayout);

    //Increment Counter
    count++;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: `Button remove = (Button)findViewById(1);` is probably returning null.

Comment: You say that you're setting the id of the view in the first couple lines of your code, but I don't see that anywhere in the "full file" that you provided. Either you're missing code in the full file, or you never set the ID of the view. Either way, can you provide the xml as well please?

Comment: You are setting the `Remove` button ID _after_ you try to get it using the ID you said you set it to.  (that order is incorrect...)

Comment: so how would I reorder it? i need to be able to click these buttons after they have been created.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:
    Button remove = (Button)findViewById(1);

This should be something like this:

```
Button remove = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRemove);   // that should be a long int
```

Answer (score 0):

The crash is likely happening from this line:

```
Button remove = (Button)findViewById(1);
```

You'll need to provide a valid ID for a `Button` within your inflated layout.  A value of `1` is not meaningful.

Comment: so whats the point of setId and What should I be using in order to be able to use a valid id?

Comment: `View.setId()` is only used if you created the `View` by calling `new`. If you are inflating a `View` from a layout (which is what `setContentView()` is doing for you) then the ID is set via the XML layout file. If you do not set the `android:id` field in the XML then you cannot retrieve the view by ID after inflation.